# Gradle Error with Appium

Tags: java, android, testing, gradle, appium

I'm trying to set up Appium testing for my Android project, but once I include it into my Gradle I get errors. At first I was getting a java.util.zip.ZipException, so I added "exclude module: 'cglib'", but now I get this error,

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My gradle file is below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ringcentral.rcandroidsdk"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled false
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
   }
}

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.4'
    // Adding this below causes errors
    compile ('io.appium:java-client:3.1.0'){
       exclude module: 'cglib'
    }

}
```